# Perfomance Testing .NET Restful WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, performance

I am using .Net RESTful WCF service in my project.
I need to do performance testing on the service to identify Memory Consumption, Allocation, Response time, Latency and all performance metrics.
Whats the tool to go for? and how to use it...
Have come across tools like CLRProfiler, AntsProfiler, .Net Performance Profiler...
But no detail available on how to use it for .Net Restful WCF Service..
I am using VS 2010 and Windows 7 for develpoment.
Walkthrough would be helpful..

Regards,
Mani.M

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Comment: Hi Pranay, thanks for the reply. I need to do it for .Net Restful WCF service. And also presently I can't access Ants Profile in my office.. Can u suggest VS 2010 tools for the same and how to profile .Net Restful WCF services

Comment: inform you network team and project manager to get download it for you because its 14 day trial version

Answer (score 2):

Make use of ANTSProfile it provides details view of each and every thing its easy to use. and there is 14 trial with full version is available.
Following is image of my project memory detail with Ants profiler. There is also series of video which help you for understanding AntsProfiler better way.

Download LInk : http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/download

[image]

Comment: Hi Pranay, thanks for the reply. I need to do it for .Net Restful WCF service. And also presently I can't access Ants Profile in my office.. Can u suggest VS 2010 tools for the same and how to profile .Net Restful WCF services